# Regular expression: retrieve one or more numbers after certain text

Tags: swift, regex

I'm trying to parse HTML code and extra some data from with using regular expressions. The website that provides the data has no API and I want to show this data in an iOS app build using Swift. The HTML looks like this:

```html
$(document).ready(function() {

var years = ['2020','2021','2022'];
var currentView = 0;
var amounts = [1269.2358,1456.557,1546.8768];
var balances = [3484626,3683646,3683070];

rest of the html code
```

What I'm trying to extract is the years, amounts and balances.

So I would like to have an array with the year in in [2020,2021,2022] same for amount and balances. In this example there are 3 years, but it could be more or less. I'm able to extra all the numbers but then I'm unable to link them to the years or amounts or balances. See this example: https://regex101.com/r/WMwUji/1, using this pattern `(\d|\[(\d|,\s*)*])`

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: No, do not use regex to parse JS code, use the dedicated parser for your language. Else, explain why you are using regex please.

Comment: I'm trying to build an iOS app (Swift) where I want to fetch data from a website that doesn't provide an API. The relevant data points are within the javascript part of the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I think there are some errors in your expression. To capture the whole number you have to use `\d+` (which matches 1 or more consecutive numbers e.g. 2020). If you need to include `.` as a separator the expression then would look like `\d+\.\d+`.
In addition using non-capturing group, `(?:)` and non-greedy matches `.*?` the regular-expression that gives the desired result for years is

```
(?:year.*?|',')(\d+)
```

This can also be modified for the amount field which would look like this:

```
(?:amounts.*?|,)(\d+\.\d+)
```

You can try it here: https://regex101.com/r/QLcFQN/1

**Edited**: in the previous Version my proposed regex was non functional and only captured the last match.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried this at regex101: https://regex101.com/r/8mY20h/1 but the output is not as expected. Group1 contains `'2022'`, but I'm looking for something that would output Match  1:`var years = ['2020','2021','2022'` and then `2020`, `2021` and `2022` as different output. So Match 1 2020, Match 2 2021 etc. Is this something that's even possible?

Comment: You are right! I have updated my solution and did some testing. I think now the expression works.

Answer (score 0):

You can continue with this regex:

```
^var (years \= (?'year'.*)|balances \= (?'balances'.*)|amounts \= (?'amounts'.*));$
```

It searches for lines with either years, balances or amount entries and names the matches acordingly. It matches the whole string within the brackets.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however I have no idea how to continue from here. I'm really new to regular expressions so any help would be very welcome

Comment: I would grab the matches and further process them in my app (you can do this in swift). There you can split the matched strings to arrays and do the other stuff.